# OneNote for Windows 10: How to Hyperlink to Another Note?

Tags: microsoft-onenote

I am using **OneNote for Windows 10**. I know that by pressing `Ctrl+K` on a word/phrase I can hyperlink it to a URL.

However, I want to do something different: **I want to hyperlink a word/phrase to another note in my notebook.**

For example, I would like the hyperlink in `Example Note 1` to open up `Example Note 2`.

Is this possible and if yes, how can I do it?

---

I'm looking for an answer compatible for OneNote for Windows 10. If this is not possible on OneNote for Windows 10, I will accept an answer for OneNote 2016.

Answer (score 1):

I actually figured it out and it's very easy.

To hyperlink to another note one simply needs to type `[[name-of-note]]` and OneNote automatically figures it out.